# Run a program before Windows-login

Tags: .net, windows, authentication

A couple of years ago, my school had a software solution from Novell. Just before the standard Windows login procedure, a special Novell-login window would open, requesting login information.

Now, I'd like to do something similar, i.e. running a program *before* anyone has logged in. Can this be done with .NET-technologies?

Comment: What do you want to program to do?

Comment: I haven't figured out that yet, just looking at the possibility to do it :)

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative authentication system (like the Novell-login window) you have to create your own authentication provider (GINA for XP, Vista and 7 use a different system). These are written in C.
You can create a service in .NET if your application doesn't need a desktop.
I've also seen a virusscanner doing a scan while Windows was booting. The application must have been some kind of console app, but I don't think a .net app can be run at that point yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(v=vs.85).aspx).

[SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GINA) related to GINA.

Comment: GINA only works in Windows versions up to XP. Vista and Windows 7 use a different system.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you can by creating a key in here...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

[image]